# Will there be any Charge distributed on the internal surface of an open metallic thin cylinder if some charge is given to the cylinder

Tags: electrostatics

If there is an open metallic thin cylinder and some charge is given to it, will there be any Charge distributed on the internal surface of the cylinder

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ratio between the length of a cylinder and its diameter.

For an infinitely long cylinder, the charge inside will be zero. For a long cylinder, there will be a little spillover near the ends. For a short cylinder, the fraction of the spillover charge will be more significant.

A possible qualitative explanation of this distribution is based on the idea that the lack of the electrostatic field inside a cylinder indicates the lack of charges on the internal surface. If, on the other hand, we can show that the electric field inside a cylinder is not zero, it would indicate the presence of charges on the internal surface.

In a limit, a short cylinder could be treated as a ring. The electric field inside a charged ring, except in its center, is not zero. This is illustrated on the diagram below, which shows that the field produced by a small segment $dQ_2$ at point A, is greater than the field produced by a larger, but more remote, segment $dQ_1$. This is because $dQ$ is proportional to the distance to $A$, while field $E$ is inversely proportional to the square of the distance.

[image]

If we extend the ring to a cylinder, $dQ$ becomes proportional to the height of the segment as well, but, since the height of the segement is, in turn, proportional to the distance to A, $dQ$ becomes proportional to the square of the distance.

So, if we integrate contributions of all segments along the length of the cylinder, from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, the net field in A will be zero. If, however, we limit the length of the cylinder, the contribution of the remote segment (to the left of A on the diagram) will be affected more than the contribution of the nearby segment (to the right of A) and, therefore, there will be some non-zero field at A, which would indicate the presence of charge on the internal surface.

Comment: Thanks V.F., I want to ask one more question. We have a thin conducting spherical shell with a small hole drilled in it. Now, some charge is given to the shell. Will there be any Charge distributed on the internal surface of the shell?

Comment: @Ganeshranakoti For a small hole there won't be much of spillover. As the size of the hole increases, the spillover will increase as well. I also completely changed the explanation in my answer. You can possibly look at the sphere using similar logic. In the sphere, of any size, the field (and charge) inside is zero due inverse square low. When you add a small hole, the changes would be small as well.